# Enter a new line and copy formula from cells above

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel macro that does the following:

1. Enter a new line at the end of document
2. copy the formulas from the cells above

So far I have this:

```
    Sub New_Delta()

    ' Go to last cell
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    LastCell = [A65536].End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Address
    Range(LastCell).Select

    ' Enter new line
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' Copy formula from cell above
    Dim oCell As Range
        For Each oCell In Selection
            If (oCell.Value = "") Then
            oCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Destination:=oCell
            End If
        Next oCell

End Sub
```

This copies the formula for the first cell "A" but not the following ones

I want to do something like `Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select` and then iterate over that up to "K" (preferably without "G" and "H")

But I'm stuck, and could really use some help.

EDIT: I want something like this (Non working pseudo code)

```
    ' Copy formula from cell above
Dim oCell As Range
        While (oCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value != "") ' If the cell above is not empty
        oCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Destination:=oCell ' Copy the formula from the cell above
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select ' Move one cell to the right
```

Comment: why would you insert a new line if the next empty line is already empty? are columns different lengths? What is the point of doing that? Sorry but its unclear to me what youre doing

Comment: probably to get the formatting from the row above (`xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`).

Comment: Yes, I want the formatting from above.
There are also other objects further down in the document that I want to keep moving down. Otherwise the rows would start to go under text boxes and buttons after a while. This seemed like a quick and painless solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply copy/insert the row before into the new row

```
Sub New_Delta()

  ' Go to last cell
  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

  ' Copy formula from cell above
  Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
  Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: I was over doing this way to much.
Thank you.